# How to filter and map a list of items by targeting a property with javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im working on a ReactJS project and in my data structure, i have 2 buttons: ATM, and PARKING:

```js
buttons: [
    {
      value: 'ATM',
      icon: 'atm',
      floors: [
        { 
          value: 'L1',
          floor: 0,
        },
        { 
          value: 'L2',
          floor: 0,
        },
      ]   
    },
    {
      value: 'PARKING',
      icon: 'parking',
      floors: [
        { 
          value: 'L1',
          floor: 0,
        },
        { 
          value: 'L2',
          floor: 0,
        },
      ]   
    },
   ],
```

I want to target the available floors values: `'L1'`, `'L2'` of ATM and display it as individual titles on HTML.

My approach is first to apply a filter for ATM, then map out the floors like so:

```js
const filteredButton = _.filter(buttons, {value : 'ATM'}); // Filter for ATM

const mappedAtm = filteredButton.map((item)=>(item.floors)) // Map for Floors

const mappedFloor = mappedAtm.map((floors)=>(floors.value)) // Map for Floors values
```

However, when I `console.log(mappedFloor)` it returns undefined

My expected output is: `"L1", "L2"`

Ideally if i get mappedFloor to work, i would then display it on html like so(on browser it should show 2 span tags):

```js
<p className="floors">
  { 
    mappedFloor.map((items, i) => (
        <span key={i}>
          {items}
        </span>
    ))
  }
</p>
```

Any suggestions and tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please try changing: `const mappedFloor = mappedAtm.map((floors)=>(floors.value))` to `const mappedFloor = mappedAtm.map(floors => floors.map(({value}) => value))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter returns an array, the first map makes it an array of array and the second expects it to be an array of objects.

To fix that, you can either use a `Array.prototype.find` instead of the filter:

```js
buttons.find((e) => e.value === 'ATM').floors.map((e) => e.value)
```

Or treat your last map as an array of array of objects and not as an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do that by making one common function that will run on button `onClick` event that will return that what you want is assume and in function passing an argument of array and property which you want to filter

```
// function that filter with respect to value property and return floors array, i assume that what you want
const filterFloors = (floorsArray,filteredProperty) => {
    return floorsArray.find((item) => {if (item.value === filteredProperty) return item.floors
    }).floors
    
} 

console.log(filterFloors(buttons,'ATM'));
console.log(filterFloors(buttons,'PARKING'))
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Would definitely keep this in mind, I believe I will be needing to use this as filter function in the near future.

Comment: do the research what the difference between filters and find.